# Pseudorandom Generator Behavior

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

Assume I have an encryption scheme $E(k,m) = (P(k,r), G(r) ⊕ m) $ and given that $G$ is a PRG , $P$ is a PRP and $r$ is a random n-bit nonce.

**My question is:**

> If I run this encryption twice with the same message but different r
>   (due to nonce behavior), will I get the same c?

I know that PRG is deterministic, but in this case, the $r$ always changes.

Please help!

Comment: What are the key generation and decryption algorithms?

Comment: Edited! For the decryption algorithm, I don't really know. This is just a thought. Does the decryption matter a lot?

Comment: Yes it matters, because if the receiver cannot decrypt, what you have is not even an encryption scheme in the first  place. Also, what is $P$?

Comment: I see, is it possible to construct one from this? I honestly didn't expect this at all.

Comment: Ok, now it's good (the decryption algorithm is obvious; it wasn't before).

Comment: So, will it generate the same message? If you need me to provide the decryption, I think it consists of (P inverse, G(r) xor c), right?

Comment: You have not precisely defined _c_ in "the same _c_?" . That could be $(P(k,r),G(r)⊕m)$ or just $G(r)⊕m$. That matters to the question, and significantly so for short messages, thus make your mind on that. I recommend that you hypothesize $c=c'$ for nounces $r$ and $r'$, find what that implies and what could cause that, then make your mind on how likely/possible that is. Hint: for fixed $k$, the transformation $r\to P(k,r)$ is a permutation, thus is injective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I run this encryption twice with the same message but different $r$ (due to nonce behavior), will I get the same $c$?

No.

Lets split this question into the two elements of $c = (c_1, c_2)$ where $c_1 = P(k,r)$ and $c_2 = G(r) ⊕ m$. Then lets start with $c_2$ where the message is actually "encrypted".

---

A good PRF will return a stream of bits indistinguishable from random. It should be a different stream each time the seed is different. However, two random streams will still have approximately half the bits identical, purely because of chance.

So lets minimize the size of $m$ to a single bit, and set $m$ to zero. The resulting stream of bits may start with a zero or one for $r=x$ or $r=y$ with $x \neq y$ . Say that they both start with $0$ or $1$ then the result of $c_2 = G(r) ⊕ m$ will be $0$ or $1$ as well.

Of course the chance that $c_2=c_2'$ is reduced by 50% for each bit added to $m$. But $c_2$ *can* be identical for the right combination of nonces.

---

The fact that $c$ consists of the permuted nonce as well confuses the matter. The $c_1$ will always be different because $P(k, r)$ will always be different - it is a permutation after all. This has however nothing to do with the message $m$ or the security of the scheme.

However, it does mean that the only answer possible is *no* given your scheme; if $c_1$ is never the same then $c$ is obviously never the same as well, even though $c_2$ is not affected.

---

Note that $G(r)$ can only be secure if $r$ behaves as a secret, i.e. has enough entropy. The size of $r$ is maximized by the size of the PRP. Basically this scheme is a stream cipher *if and only if* $r$ contains enough entropy. In that case $P(k, r)$ will be a form of key wrapping.

Comment: So, at a very high-level view, G(r) ⊕ m will always produce different cipher with the same m, right?

Comment: Huh? No I just explained why not. If the stream cipher generated by $G(r)$ creates the same key stream then the ciphertexts will be identical. However, the larger the stream the less likely this becomes. I'm not sure what you mean with "very high-level view".

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't read it properly. I think for simplicity's sake $r$ random n-bit nonce is a large-enough seed that will not cause the stream cipher to generate the same key stream. Correct?

Comment: Well, again, consider a "stream" of a single bit. There is still a 50% chance that two entirely different values of $r$ will generate the same key stream. Random doesn't mean different. It is perfectly possible to toss two sixes in a row with a perfectly balanced dice. But I shall amend my answer for an n-bit sized $r$, because **I** skipped that.